# Wintersmith: error Error loading plugin './node_modules/wintersmith-coffee/': Cannot find module './plugin'

Tags: coffeescript, wintersmith

I built a site with wintersmith in November of 2013. It's live at http://powma.com

I'm coming back to it, but it's not building :-{

I don't mind getting my hands dirty, but I don't know where to start.  I'm getting this error:

```
error Error loading plugin './node_modules/wintersmith-coffee/': Cannot find module './plugin'
```

Any suggestions?

Thanks!

Mike

### UPDATE

Hey, this is because the coffeescript wasn't getting compiled.

I installed it globally, but that didn't help.

```
$ sudo npm install -g coffee-script
```

I manually compiled it and moved to other errors. Any suggestions for what's missing?

```
$ coffee -c plugin.coffee
```

Here's my config.json:

```
{
  "locals":
    { "url": "http://localhost:8080"
    , "title": "Powma"
    , "subTitle": "Linking you to technology"
    , "motto": "We build exceptions sites and applications to connect people to products, services, and each other."
    , "owner": "Michael Cole"
    , "profilePicture": "/static/img/profile-professional.jpg"
    , "inlineSpriteMaxBytes" : 10000
    },
  "views": "./views",
  "plugins":
    [ "./node_modules/wintersmith-coffee/"
    , "./node_modules/wintersmith-stylus/"
    ],
  "require": {
    "moment": "moment",
    "_": "underscore",
    "typogr": "typogr"
  },
  "jade": {
    "pretty": true
  },
  "markdown": {
    "smartLists": true,
    "smartypants": true
  },
  "paginator": {
    "perPage": 3
  }
}
```

And package.json:

```
{
  "name": "Powma-com",
  "version": "0.1.1",
  "private": true,
  "engines": {
    "node": "0.10.17"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "moment": "2.0.x",
    "underscore": "1.5.x",
    "typogr": "0.5.x",
    "wintersmith": "2.0.x",
    "wintersmith-stylus": "git://github.com/MichaelJCole/wintersmith-stylus.git#master",
    "wintersmith-coffee": "0.2.x",
    "express": "3.4.x",
    "sendgrid": "~0.3.0-rc.1.7",
    "express-validator": "~0.8.0",
    "underscore-express": "0.0.4"
  }
}
```

This is a new dev laptop I'm working with so that may be part of the problem.

I worked around the issue, but didn't fix it.  Do I really need to manually compile the coffeescript?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved this issue by explicitly specifying plugin.coffee in the `config.json` file.

`{
...other stuff...
"plugins":
    [ "./node_modules/wintersmith-coffee/plugin.coffee"
    , "./node_modules/wintersmith-stylus/plugin.coffee"
    ],
...more stuff...
}`

Comment: Ok, I might have misunderstood the question then. In the config.json you showed in the question it is not the same. I did exactly as you did at first but I needed to be even more specific and add the "...../plugin.coffee" file explicitly to the path to get it to work. If this is what you actually do then you should update your question.

Comment: Yes! That did the trick.  My eyes saw, but my brain did not see.  Thanks for the followup!

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you're missing wintersmith-coffee in node_modules; make sure you have it installed locally with `npm install wintersmith-coffee`. You can also try removing it from `config.json` if you're not using it anywhere.

It would also be helpful to see both your `config.json` and `package.json`. Also make sure you run an `npm install` and `npm update` to make sure you have everything referenced in `package.json` installed and updated.

**Update**

Not having CoffeeScript installed could have been the issue. After installing that globally, I'm not sure if all of your shell sessions will pick up the command and use it without being restarted. With a new shell session, see if you can build the site. You can also try testing Wintersmith in isolation of your site. Try generating a sample site with `wintersmith new somepath` and see if you can run `wintersmith build` there. That would be a good start for narrowing down your issues between your site and your workstation setup.

Comment: Hey, I updated the question.  Yes, it's a coffeescript issue.

Comment: Hi, wintersmith build works in the new version, but not the old one.  Not sure what the difference is, but you're right, it's a start.